# How can Haku perform hand seals with only one hand?

Tags: naruto

In the *Land of the Waves* arc, it can be seen that Haku performs handseals with only one hand. That must be something special, because a.) even Kakashi was surprised to see that, and b.) that's never seen again somewhere (except I forgot it).

How is that possible? Is that a special technique? Was it ever explained in the manga/anime?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ebisu explains (in Chapter 90) that to perform a ninjutsu or genjutsu, a shinobi needs to go through 2 steps.

1. Build up the necessary amount of chakra for that jutsu.
2. Control the chakra for that jutsu using various hand seals.

Haku's ability to do hand seals with one hand shows his exceptional skill in the chakra control (at step 2).

There are other ways in which a shinobi's prowess with hand seals has been demonstrated. Senju Tobirama could use the Water Dragon Bullet Technique with just one hand seal, while it normally requires 44. Uchiha Sasuke has been able to use Chidori without any hand seals, and Fire Techniques with just one hand seal. (He needed more seals for both the jutsu when he started.)

The other shinobi shown to be capable of one-handed seals is Guren from the Three Tails filler arc. (Source: Narutopedia)

Comment: Whoah, that explains a lot. I always wondered how the seals are combined, but when it's possible to change the procedure by pure skill, it's clear. Didn't know this, thanks!

Comment: I think Granny Chiyo performed a one hand seal too, when she made the toy bird after the fight with the Itachi dupe.

Comment: Where is source link?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Why do you need a source link for that? I have mentioned the chapter number, anyone interested can read it on their own. The point about Guren is a trivia entry, not even related to the question and it is from a filler arc, so I consider it not worth the trouble to post a link. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Hand seals are there to control chakra, but if you already have amazing chakra control, you can use your techniques without them.

> Madara was able to use Shattered Heaven (the giant meteors he used on the Tsuchikage) with only 3 hand seals despite it being an extremely taxing technique powerful enough to lay waste to an entire battalion.

Comment: We haven't seen those in the anime, it's possible that he used more seals (with the three pairs of hands)

Comment: The wiki notes he did 1 seal with each pair of Susano´o hands.

Comment: I honestly don't know where the folks over there get their information, but since it hasn't been specifically stated in the manga, I see it as speculation (I doubt the author said anything about it)