# Can a ninjutsu be executed without the use of hand seals?

Tags: naruto

Is it possible to execute any ninjutsu without using handseals?

Comment: Look at the answer to this: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/how-can-haku-perform-hand-seals-with-only-one-hand where it says that Sasuke can do Chidori without using any hand seals.

Comment: As @kuwaly said, [this answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/2590/49) already answers your question. As such, I marked this one as a duplicate of the other.